# Controlling tasks within Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, json, swift

Working in Swift 2.0, on IOS 9.2.1 using Xcode 7.2

Learning Swift 2.0 and I have written a routine that creates a NSURL Session, gets back some JSON data and then parses it. It works great...

BUT I some help in understanding how make this work as in get the outer function, share_list_folders to wait until the **task** here truly completes so I can return the result?

```
var parsedJson:[String:AnyObject] = [:]

func shared_list_folders() {

    // **** list_folders (shared) ****
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/list_folders")!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.addValue("Bearer ab-XXX", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        //print("Response: \(response)")


        let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("Body: \(strData)\n\n")
        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers);               

                self.jsonParser(jsonResult)
                for (key, value) in self.parsedJson {
                    print("key2 \(key) value2 \(value)")
                }
        } catch {
            print("Bang")
        }
    })

    task.resume()
    let string2return = parsedJson["path_lower"] as? String
    return(string2return)!
}
```

Its not really a completion, cause task will go off and do its own thing and share_list_folders will complete? Obviously I don't get the path_lower value here, until its too late... looked at delegates? And I tried, but then I run into issued with the completion block...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed `NSURLSession` after resuming it's task go away and do it's job which requires time. It's part of asynchronous programming when you have to deal with situation when something is calculated/prepared in another thread. Under the hood `NSURLSession` has own thread and there is waiting for server response. Then invokes `completionHandler` on main thread. That's a simplified theory. Going back to your question:

It's obviously that you have to wait for server response. As in another languages code is executed line by line, so you can't return anything as you wrote. The answer is: use [closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

Function you declare could use delegate as well but let's focus on closures:

```
func shared_list_folders(completion: (string: String?, error: ErrorType?) -> Void) {
    // **** list_folders (shared) ****
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/list_folders")!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.addValue("Bearer ab-XXX", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    //print("Response: \(response)")
        if let error = error {
            completion(string: nil, error: error)
            return
        }

        let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("Body: \(strData)\n\n")
        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers);               

            let parsedJson = self.jsonParser(jsonResult) // I assume this returns parsedJson?
            let string2return = parsedJson["path_lower"] as? String

            completion(string: string2return, error: nil)
        } catch { // here we have an error
            completion(string: nil, error: error)
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I don't have to time test tonight, but will do so tomorrow morning! And surely accept your answer!! THANK YOU again, the syntax behind closures is still an element I am trying to get into my head around !!

Comment: There's some sort of typo: `} catch {`  should be `} catch let error {`

Comment: @CouchDeveloper There is no need to declare explicitly error in catch closure for standard do-catch instructions.

Comment: @neru But you are passing the error from the request in the completion handler - which is `nil` in case the request succeeded. You are not passing the error thrown from within `do` clause. Do I missing something?

Comment: `nil` error of type `NSError` from `completionHandler` will be covered by internally defined error of type `ErrorType` from `do-catch` clause. In other word error from `catch` will replace `NSError` in scope of `catch` closure.

Comment: @neru Interesting. If this is actually the case, I would consider this a language bug: consider you intentionally want to pass the outer error - how would this work?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I would pass error from response out of catch scope. I edited my answer to handle this situation.

Comment: @neru You are totally right regarding that the implicit error parameter covers an outer parameter (compiler does not warn or signal anything). I think this is not a well thought feature. IMHO, this is a prime example of violating "The principle of least astonishment"  ;)  - And handling the error early from the response is also a good idea - you have my vote already :)